Probability that a uniform random variable + a constant be greater than another uniform random variable
I am trying to understand a model of probabilistic voting from the following paper https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/pubeco/v96y2012i1p10-19.html and the one component I struggle with goes as follows:
ΔU is some positive constant, η ~U[-1/(2ψ);1/(2ψ)], σ~U[-1/2 ; 1/2] .
We are told that the event A, i.e. incumbent being reelected, happens if η + ΔU > σ .
Then the article goes on to say "the probability of reelection is just (eq.1):
p = 1/2 - ψΔU
I would like to know how to get to this result.
Let me add that I know there are several questions that have been asked about the probability of a random variable being greater than another or how to calculate the pdf of the sum of two random variables; I have read them, it has helped me, but I can't manage to apply it exactly to my case (which probably says a lot about my mathematical literacy admittedly).
What I tried :
I managed to get a good intuition (I think) of why the probability p is what is it by looking at it graphically. That is I plotted for ΔU = 0, η+ΔU on the x-axis and σ on the y-axis and convinced myself that P(η > σ = 1/2) i.e. does not depend on ψ which is the first part of (eq.1). Then I noticed that if I increase the value of ψ (say >1 for instance), then the distrubtion of η gets "narrower" and so the shift of the pdf of η that ΔU represents increases P(η + ΔU > σ) more than when ψ is small (<1 for instance), thus that the effect of ΔU on the probability of A increases with ψ (second term of eq.1).
But when I try to get this result analytically I fail because I do not where to put the bounds on the integrals. I first tried to do :
P(η + ΔU > σ) = P(ΔU > σ -η) but I got messed up with the convolution to find the pdf of Z = σ -η . Last I tried to just integrate over the pdf of η+ΔU and of σ but I don't know how to specify the bounds of the integrals because I somehow feel like depending on whether ψ > 1 or not then the lower bound should either be -1/2 or -1/(2ψ) and vice-versa for the upper bound.
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Let $X\sim \mathcal U (0,a)$ and $X\sim \mathcal U (0,b)$ be independent random variables with $a<b$. Then, using the convolution formula $f_{X+Y}(z)=f_{X}*f_{Y}(z)$, it can be shown that
$$f_{X+Y}(z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{z}{ab},& 0<z<a\\
\frac{1}{b}, & a \le z\le b \\
\frac{1}{b}-\frac{z-b}{ab},& b<z<a+b.
\end{cases} \tag {1}$$

Assuming $\Delta U>0$, $\eta \sim \mathcal U [-1/(2\psi);1/(2\psi)]$, $\sigma \sim \mathcal U [-1/2 ; 1/2]$, the condition
$$\eta + \Delta U > \sigma$$
can be written as
$$X+Y>c$$
with
$$X=-\sigma+1/2\sim \mathcal U (0,a=1), \\Y=\eta+1/(2\psi) \sim \mathcal U (0,b=1/\psi),\\ c=1/2+1/(2\psi)-\Delta U.$$
Now using (1), you can find the probability $$\mathbb P (X+Y>c)=\int_{c}^{a+b}f_{X+Y}(z)\text{d}z.$$
When $0<\psi<1$ and $1<1/2+1/(2\psi)-\Delta U<1/\psi$, we have
$$\int_{1/2+1/(2\psi)-\Delta U}^{1+1/\psi}f_{X+Y}(z)\text{d}z=1/2\color{red}{+}\psi\Delta U, \tag{2}$$
which differs from what given in the OP (and the paper, I personally checked the paper). For any $\Delta U>0$:
$$\mathbb P \left (X+Y>1/2+1/(2\psi)-\Delta U \right )>\frac{1}{2}$$
considering $X+Y-1/2-1/(2\psi)$ has a symmetric distribution.
Without the above calculation, one can personally make sure that the re-election probability
$$\mathbb P (\eta + \Delta U > \sigma)=\mathbb P (\eta - \sigma>-\Delta U )>\frac{1}{2}$$
is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ since $\eta - \sigma $ has a symmetric distribution, and $1/2-\psi\Delta U$ is not correct. Thus, I am sure that the authors made a mistake unless the re-election event should have been defined as $\eta + \Delta U < \sigma$ (which seems not correct, please check the concept from a modeling perspective).
Moreover, in the paper, as I personally checked in the first column of page 12, the authors did not assume  $0<\psi<1$ and $1<1/2+1/(2\psi)-\Delta U<1/\psi$, so the proposed formula (2) is not always correct even after correcting it by replacing $-$ with $+$. For example, if $\psi>1$ and  $1/\psi<1/2+1/(2\psi)-\Delta U<1$, the probability becomes:
$$1/2\color{red}{+\Delta U}.$$

Great, thank you for your answer and for adding the extra precision regarding necessary assumptions for psi and delta U.

@flafont11 you are very welcome! Considering that the incorrect formula is used in the rest of the paper I guess the results and insights of the paper need to be carefully checked.
